# backslash operator in MATLAB for a vector

Tags: matlab, backslash, least-squares

In MATLAB let us type

```
A = [0.1195952380, 0.2552619050, 0.3235000000,...
     0.1289285710, 0.6675476190, -0.0770000000,...
     0.1973809520];

and

b0 = 1.7250238100;
```

If I use backslash operator as `A \ b0`, the result is

```
[0         0         0         0    2.5841         0         0]
```

and if I use

```
pinv(A)*b0
```

we get the answer as:

```
0.2985    0.6370    0.8073    0.3217    1.6659   -0.1922    0.4926
```

But many documents which talk about backslash operator, say that both the operations should result in the same answer. Why is this not so in this case?

Can anybody help me in this regard?

Thanks,

Babu.

Comment: I think what you are doing with A\b0 is A*pinv(b0)

Comment: Perhaps you could show which documentation you are talking about?

Comment: @AnderBiguri That would not give zeros as output as `pinv(b0)` is just a positive scalar.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin yeah, I was wrong, sorry my mistake.

Comment: Related article: [What is the difference between PINV and MLDIVIDE when I solve A*x=b?](https://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3TPS3Y/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-3TPS3Y).

Answer (score 2):

Your system is very much underdetermined.

`A\b0` finds one solution to the equation.

`pinv(A)*b0` simly finds another solution.

Both are correct, but obviously they find a different solution due to different algorithms being used.

You can check that they are the same by seeing that

```
A*(A\b0) - A*(pinv(A)*b0)
```

is effectively zero

Comment: No. Very much UNDERdefined. One row, many columns, so only one piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to backslashes, I always get confused. My remedy is: write **explicitly** the system of equations you are trying to solve (at least in least-squares sense) and then try and match it to the documentation.

In your example the system you are trying to solve is

A * x = b0

For this system you have 7 unknown and only one equation (b0 is a scalar). 
Therefore, your system is under-determined as pointed by [Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15407366/1714410), and it is reasonably to expect several different (yet equivalent) solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. As the system is under determined, we will have infinite solutions. Which one among these is the best? What criteria does backslash and pinv impose to give the corresponding answers? If you look at '\' solution, the resulting vector is all zeros except at one point. That turns out to be the same index where 'x' is maximum. I could not figure this out. Thanks in advance for any help. . . . .

Comment: @LeaderBabu it seems like you have `L1` vs `L2` regularization here.

Comment: @Shai - no, it is not L1 regularization. Read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this system is UNDER-determined (NOT OVER, as Dennis said.) Since you had some followup questions, let me go into more depth.

With one row in A, you have essentially one equation, in 7 unknowns. You can essentially just set any 6 of those unknowns to zero, then solve for the 7th. This is what backslash does. It will pick the unknown such that the result has the minimum contribution from any noise, thus here, the unknown with the LARGEST absolute coefficient in the A matrix. This is why the 5th unknown was non-zero in the result.

In fact, the solution will live in a 6-dimensional set. We can freely add any linear combination of vectors from the null row-space of A to that solution and get another equally (mathematically) valid solution based on the linear system.

```
A = [0.1195952380, 0.2552619050, 0.3235000000,...
     0.1289285710, 0.6675476190, -0.0770000000,...
     0.1973809520];

null(A)
ans =
   -0.3070   -0.3891   -0.1551   -0.8029    0.0926   -0.2374
    0.9176   -0.1044   -0.0416   -0.2155    0.0249   -0.0637
   -0.1044    0.8676   -0.0528   -0.2731    0.0315   -0.0808
   -0.0416   -0.0528    0.9790   -0.1089    0.0126   -0.0322
   -0.2155   -0.2731   -0.1089    0.4364    0.0650   -0.1666
    0.0249    0.0315    0.0126    0.0650    0.9925    0.0192
   -0.0637   -0.0808   -0.0322   -0.1666    0.0192    0.9507
```

The columns of null(A) are these basis vectors of the null-subspace. As it turns out, sometimes the backslash solution will not be preferred, since it somewhat arbitrarily chooses elements to set to zero. A different solution is to use pinv(A)*b0.

```
pinv(A)
ans =
    0.1730
    0.3693
    0.4680
    0.1865
    0.9657
   -0.1114
    0.2855

pinv(A)*b0
ans =
    0.2985
    0.6370
    0.8073
    0.3217
    1.6659
   -0.1922
    0.4926
```

pinv(A) is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of A. It uses a singular value decomposition to produce that result, so it will be slower than backslash in general, but here the difference will be trivial. The characteristic of the pinv solution that is sometimes of interest is it has the smallest norm of all possible such solutions.

```
b0 = 1.7250238100;
norm(A\b0)
ans =
    2.5841

norm(pinv(A)*b0)
ans =
    2.0748
```

Is one solution better than another? Not really. Sometimes we care about the difference, and you may care to choose one of them over the other. But if you have only one equation, then you must accept that any of the possible solutions may be as good as any other.

There are BAD solutions we might choose of course. For example, this next solution is in theory, an equally valid choice, if a silly one:

```
x2 = x1 + null(A)*10*randn(6,1)
x2 =
         -4.09413481014061
          13.5483342562954
          13.4850200598594
          6.44121071558247
         -13.4923071847226
           7.3358845464619
           15.883243834012
```

I've chosen to add in a random linear combination of the nullspace vectors of A. It looks like it gives the same solution A*x2.

```
A*x2
ans =
                1.72502381
```

But when we subtract off b0, we see that the larger coefficients in x2 are a problem. These coefficients have exaggerated noise in those least significant bits, producing a subtly worse solution.

```
A*x2 - b0
ans =
      6.66133814775094e-16
```

Compare that to the residual from the other solutions, and we see that it is arguably worse.

```
A*x0 - b0
ans =
     0

A*x1 - b0
ans =
      2.22044604925031e-16
```

Of course, since eps is

```
eps
ans =
      2.22044604925031e-16
```

this is about the limit of our hopes on this problem.

Of course, when you have MORE equations than unknowns (here more rows than columns in A) AND A is of full rank, then the two solutions should be the same to within numerical trash. This is what you have read, but that only applies on over-determined problems. Your problem is not over-determined, but under-determined.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is underdetermined. That is, there are indefinitely many solutions.

Say your `A` has `m` more columns than rows.

The backslash operator treats these systems by setting some `m` undetermined components of the solutions to zero, cf. this [Source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/238504&anno=2) .

Contrarily, `pinv` returns the Moore-Penrose `A^+` inverse of `A` that most likely has a different zero pattern.

That's why you have differences in `pinv` and `\` for underdetermined systems. For overdetermined system, these operators indeed give the same solutions.